# Mapstruct @Mapper's uses attribute not working

Tags: mapstruct

I am facing an issue with one of my Mapstruct mappers not using another mapper with **`@Mapper(uses =`**

Our `ValidationSupportNeedMapper` maps from entities to DTOs. One `ValidationSupportNeedEntity` contains an `ActivityEntity` property and I am trying to map from this property to an `Activity` DTO.

The issue is therefore with a nested object i.e. `ActivityEntity` to `Activity`.

Here is the source code:

From **ValidationSupportNeedMapper.java**:

```
@Mapper(uses = {LifecycleErrorMessagesMapper.class, ActivityMapper.class})
public interface ValidationSupportNeedMapper {

   ValidationSupportNeed toValidationSupportNeed(ValidationSupportNeedEntity source);

...
```

From **ActivityMapper.java**:

```
@Component
public class ActivityMapper {

    public Activity toActivity(ActivityEntity activity) {
       //Implementation
    }

    public ActivityEntity toActivityEntity(Activity activity) {
        //Implementation
    }

}
```

From **ValidationSupportNeedEntity.java** (Entity)

```
public class ValidationSupportNeedEntity {

    private ActivityEntity activityEntity;
```

From **ValidationSupportNeed.java** (DTO)

```
public class ValidationSupportNeed implements AutoValidated {
      private Activity validationActivity;
```

However Mapstruct seems to ignore the **`uses=`** attribute on the `@Mapper` annotation and goes ahead and generates its own mapping method as follows:

```
   @Override
    public ValidationSupportNeed toValidationSupportNeed(ValidationSupportNeedEntity source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ValidationSupportNeed validationSupportNeed = new ValidationSupportNeed();

        validationSupportNeed.setValidationActivity( validationSupportNeedEntityToActivity( source ) );
    ...
  }

    protected Activity validationSupportNeedEntityToActivity(ValidationSupportNeedEntity validationSupportNeedEntity) {
        if ( validationSupportNeedEntity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Activity activity = new Activity();

        activity.setCode( validationSupportNeedEntity.getValidationActivityCode() );

        return activity;
    }
```

What am I missing? Can someone please help?

**edit**: `ActivityMapper` is not autowired into the `ValidationSupportNeedMapper` implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a mapping annotation sorted the issue:

```
@Mapping(source = "activityEntity", target = "validationActivity")
ValidationSupportNeed toValidationSupportNeed(ValidationSupportNeedEntity source);
```

Notice the names of the attributes are different.